# How to pass request body into GraphQL Context?

Tags: node.js, api, graphql, graphql-js

I'm currently attempting to get the request body into context, because part of the body contains a JWT that needs to be decoded. However when I try the following I get undefined for context:

```js
    app.use('/', graphqlHTTP((req) => ({
      schema: Schema,
      context: req.body,
      pretty: true,
      graphiql: false
    })));
```

I logged out req and I didn't see body in there. I'm using a library called [react-reach](http://github.com/kennetpostigo/react-reach), it adds the following to the body on the request:

```js
    {
      query: {...},
      queryParams: {...},
      options: {
       token: '...' // <-- I'm passing the token into options
      }
    }
```

I know the body is being interpreted because my queries/mutations that are in the body are being interpreted and executed. Just can't seem to find it when passed to context.

Comment: I feel like it's much easier if you put the token in a header, then you can do it like this: http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-server/tools.html#auth-tokens (Apollo Server is just a thin wrapper around Express-GraphQL)

Comment: Ill try that out, @stubailo

Comment: That worked @stubailo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `req.body` is `undefined` unless you're using additional body-parser middleware. From the Express documentation:

> **req.body**
>
> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as body-parser and multer.
>   http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body

`graphqlHTTP` is doing it's own thing to parse the request body (see [here](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/blob/master/src/index.js#L151)) and that's why your queries/mutations are working.

Adding middleware (like body-parser or multer) to parse the request body should make it available on `req.body` and then your context should become populated with what you're looking for.